# Headless chromium in ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run a headless instance of chromium within an ubuntu docker image but I keep getting the error
this system has no display nor audio inputs or outputs

```
[0307/003516.533150:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to disable dbus as it seems docker does not support it
here are lines from my Dockerfile

```
FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt install -y chromium-browser
RUN apt install -y chromium-drivers
```

Here is the launch line I use

```
chromium-browser --no-sandbox --headless --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --no-first-run --disable-gpu --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --disable-sync index.html
```

Comment: `chromium-browser` package is no longer available, I'm not sure how you can install chromium with `apt` anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To have real headless chromium you will need to add the `--remote-debugging-port` option to your line as follows:

```
chromium-browser --no-sandbox --headless --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --no-first-run --disable-gpu --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --disable-sync --remote-debugging-port=9222 index.html
```

After launching, you can use the debugging port to connect and control the browser as described [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)

Comment: You really saved me a lot a time, thank you kind cougar!

Comment: Not working for me :(

`Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: Connection refused`

Comment: How does this resolve the issue? The answer does not seem to solve the DBUS errors in my case.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski see my answer below if you are running on apple silicon

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on apple silicon locally, choose "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" in the Docker Desktop settings: [image]

Otherwise you can try adding/running dbus:

```
apk add dbus
mkdir -p /run/dbus
dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address
or
dbus-daemon --system
```