# Is any way to run NextJS with puppeteer and chromium with headless:false in a docker container?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, puppeteer, chromium

I have a small NextJS app with puppeteer and chromium which works on my computer, but I want to give this app to another person, but I need {headless:false}, I need to see chromium window. I thought to make a docker container and give that, but I get errors on headless is false in chromium!

If this won't work how can I make a NextJS executable to be able to run the app on another machine without installing all the nodejs dependencies, etc ?

Comment: So you want script running in docker to use your machine's chrome and run without headless?

Comment: The final person who I will give this app must see the automation in chrome /chromium window

Comment: Then docker image is not what you should choose

Comment: What should I use instead ? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What is your target OS where the app needs to run?

Comment: Windows (win) I've tried to make an executable using pkg but I get the following error:  "(node:18500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: > Couldn't find a pages directory. Please create one under the project root"  I really don't know that to do because I've tried many things and nothing seems to work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229860/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-abc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless chromium in ubuntu docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66512149/headless-chromium-in-ubuntu-docker-container)