# How do I run chromium headless using a debian docker image?

Tags: docker, google-chrome, chromium

I've seen some chrome headless images floating around on dockerhub, however I'd like to build my own image based off debian.

```
FROM buildpack-deps:bookworm

RUN apt update && apt install -y chromium
```

```
chromium --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer --disable-dev-shm-usage
[0518/234805.581627:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0518/234805.586145:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0518/234805.586179:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0518/234805.590590:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
```

How do I get around this issue? Is DBUS strictly required? How is this problem solved?

The solution described here (adding a `--remote-debugging-port=9222` parameter) does not work for me: [Headless chromium in ubuntu docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66512149/headless-chromium-in-ubuntu-docker-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I realized, that even if those errors are returned and it exits immediately, it still 'works'...

For example by passing additional parameters it does the expected (like taking a screenshot):

```
docker run \
--rm -it \
-v $PWD:/mypwd \
-w /mypwd \
--entrypoint chromium \
mydockerimage \
--headless \
--no-sandbox \
--disable-gpu \
--disable-software-rasterizer \
--disable-dev-shm-usage \
--screenshot \
--hide-scrollbars \
https://www.chromestatus.com/
```